# CSS issue in Safari and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari, css-transitions

I have a input fixed to `width:0` and `border: 0` ready for css transition (Onclick expand to 75%) Everything works fine but in Safari and IE width is not 0. I can see a 2px (aprox.) width of this input field.

This is my CASS code:

```
input#s {
    width:0;        
    border:0px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Georgia, Serif;
    color: #999; 
    font-variant: small-caps;
    vertical-align:baseline;     
    -webkit-transition:width 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:width 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition:width 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

Anybody could help me?
Maybe I have to fix with `font-size:0;` and `:focus` one set correct `font-size`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `border: none 0;` A known ie hack.

Comment: Not working. I think is a with:0 problem. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Try aslo outline: 0; Would be great if you show us an example or reproduce the problem in a fiddle.

Comment: Resolved! I'm really stupid. Problem was padding property was inherit from other style. I set padding:0;´ and everything working!